# Displaying image from a class attribute in a button

Tags: c#, wpf

i need to display an image which is from a class attribute inside a button, the binding doesn't work.

This is how i proceed:

i have a class Products that contains ProductImage of type system.drawable.image and some other strings.

XAML code :

```
<Button Content="{Binding ProductImage}" Name="ImageButton"></Button>
```

the button is showing with Content : System.Drawing.Bitmap in it.

any help Please.

EDIT : i found important to add the Window2.XAML.cs file

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionManager.ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products", connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            var list = new List<ProductsBLL>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ProductsBLL product = new ProductsBLL();

                product.ProductId = (int) reader[0];
                product.ProductName = (string) reader[1];
                product.ProductReference = (string) reader[2];
                product.ProductColor = (string) reader[3];
                var imagems = (byte[]) reader[4];
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagems);
                product.ProductImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                product.ProductDescription = (string) reader[5];
                product.ProductUnitPrice = (decimal) reader[6];
                product.ProductUnitInStock = (int) reader[7];
                product.ProductUnitInCommand = (int) reader[8];

                list.Add(product);
                product = null;
            }

            ProductsListView.ItemsSource = list;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, e.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of your `ProductImage` property is currently `System.Drawing.Image`, which is WinForms, not WPF. A `System.Drawing.Image` can not be drawn directly by a WPF Image control.

You should change the property type to [`System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx):

```
public ImageSource ProductImage { get; set; }
```

Now you would create an instance of either `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` or 
`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame` as value of the property. Note that the `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` must be set, because you want to dispose of the stream right after loading the image.

```
byte[] imageBuffer = ...

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
{
    product.ProductImage = BitmapFrame.Create(
        memoryStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```

or

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    product.ProductImage = bitmapImage;
}
```

Finally (as already said in the other answer) you would have to use an `Image` control as the Button's `Content`:

```
<Button Name="ImageButton">
    <Image Source="{Binding ProductImage}" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Image` control as place holder for `Bitmap` :

```
<Button Name="ImageButton">
    <Image Source="{Binding ProductImage}" />
</Button>
```

Comment: i've done so, and the image is not displayed in the XAML code i have a 'cannot resolve symbole ProductImage' error, should i do something is the xaml.cs file ?

Comment: in the class.xaml.cs file i only create instances of products and assign to ProductImage an image from a database.

Comment: I can't test the code right now, but if there wasn't any error when binding to `ProductImage` like you post in question, I can't see why there is such "*cannot resolve symbol `ProductImage`*" error now..

Comment: you can check my edit, i added my cs file., after i retrieve data from database, i need to display image in listview, and every image in button, if you can help please .

Comment: can i get some help :/